# How should I license my game so others may not distribute copies?

Tags: legal, licensing, distribution

I've created a game and I'm unsure how to license it or what that means.

I've heard of [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) licenses. Should I use that?

I want it so that people that download my game **cannot** remix or distribute copies, even for non commercial purposes. What should I do in such a case?

Comment: Duplicate of ["What is the “default” software license?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/what-is-the-default-software-license) on programmers.stackexchange.com - no license terms implies "all rights reserved" which appears to be your intentions. The various Creative Commons flavors are all more or less pro-redistribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you have exclusive copyright for every creative work you produce, which means nobody is allowed to distribute it except you unless you give them explicit permission.

The purpose of a license is to give the end-user rights they would normally not have. So when you don't add any license terms whatsoever, it means your end-users have no right to redistribute your software. Technically, they don't even have the right to *use* your software. That's what an [End-User License Agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) is for. As you certainly know, it is common practice to have the user agree to it with a click during the installation of your game and also drop a copy in the directory where it was installed for later reference.

All the creative commons licenses allow non-commercial and unchanged redistribution, so when you want people to receive copies of your game only from you, the CC licenses are not what you are looking for.

Comment: would I be able to sue someone if they distributed my game without my permission then? Thanks so much for your answer. It was extremely helpful!

Comment: @Derpybunneh Yes, they would violate your copyright which should give you the right to sue them for copyright violation. Ask a lawyer or on https://law.stackexchange.com for details how to proceed in this situation.

Comment: _"Technically, they don't even have the right to use your software."_ This is incorrect, even in jurisdictions where EULAs are enforceable. Copyright grants the author of a work an exclusive right to make and publish copies, but not to use, read, view, listen to, etc. This end-users are already allowed to do without a licence.